# Constant var in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, constants

I'm having a little problem, I have a variable called 'widgets' and I want to store it's original value in 'storeWigets' and even if I update the value of 'widgets' my variable 'storeWidgets' stays with the original value of 'widgets'.

```
var widgets=["1","2","3","4"];
var storeWidgets;
storeWidgets = widgets;
widgets[0]=0;
alert(storeWidgets);
```

I have an [example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nopzjm0h/1/), I need that in the end my 'storeWidgets' keeps the value ["1","2","3","4"] but it keeps returning me ["0","2","3","4"]

Comment: Objects are copied using reference. Try `storeWidgets = widgets.slice()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var widgets=["1","2","3","4"];
var storeWidgets;
storeWidgets = widgets.slice(0);;
widgets[0]=0;
alert(widgets);
alert(storeWidgets);
```